# How do i check the RAM on my Ubuntu sever?

Tags: linux

I'm using an old laptop that originally had 512MB of RAM and installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 I upgraded the old 512MB memory card to 1GB memory card, and now I just want to check how much RAM my laptop Ubuntu Server actually recognized.

If someone knows the Ubuntu Server command to checking RAM that is being recognized, please let me know.

Comment: "the Ubuntu Server command"... sigh. Also known as "linux command".

Answer (score 5):

Use the following in terminal

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: A bit on the short answer side...

Answer (score 2):

GUI: **Applications -> System Tools -> Sysinfo**

Console command: **free -m**

Comment: Thank you for this consice version...      Good looking out guys!